# how to get http status value?

Tags: http, http-status-codes, http-status

first of all i asked something before and i got another question
please take a look this one first

[I send some values to another url and about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43462707/i-send-some-valuse-to-another-url-and-about-that/43463446#43463446)

i made a question and got an answer, and finally i have another question
if like i said that above question, i send some values to other url 
using spring and httpclient like this,

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://test.com");
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(values arrayList));
(values arrayLists that i made is 
arrayList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name","mister"));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

if i send some value like that,how i get http status value at the receiving page, "http://test.com" if i assume that receiving page using spring and java
how to code to get http status value?

Comment: The http status is something the http server sends as part if the response, there is no such thing in the request, so the sever cannot "get" that value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43462707/i-send-some-valuse-to-another-url-and-about-that/43463446#43463446 this question that i make answered there is http status value......so i asked this....then you mean there is no way to get http status value or there is no http status value at request??

Comment: It appears that you did not yet understand how the http protocol works, the difference between request and response. Once more: the request does _not_ carry a status code, the response does. I suggest you take a look at some raw http communication to understand the details (using a network sniffer for example) or at least you open your browsers console and inspect the details of requests you see in the network tab in there.

Comment: that is what i want to know. <request doesn't carry status value>...really thank you to help me. i read https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html this one but i couldn't understand yet...my team manager told me http always has request and response...but..i only wrote a response....then what is my request...?i just send some values to that test url...i think i'm going crazy..that test url is request? what is my request?help me...

Comment: A client always sends a request to a server, that is how the two terms are defined. The Server returns a response, which indeed does include a status code. It might be that you currently ignore that response, but is there. As said: take a look at the communication you initiate with your request. You will find a server response...