# When I wrote an api document, I don't know how to write request and response side

Tags: http, http-status-codes, api-doc, http-status

I made some code for sending data to other url and that was written with spring and java, using 'httpclient' class. About that code please check this question that I made

[how to get http status value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43464321/how-to-get-http-status-value)

I have a problem with request and response of http and that was solved.
My question was about http status and finally I got the truth that request doesn't carry status value.

Anyway, so I have to made some documents for our code to show to customers and I'm confused of response tab.

What I wrote is response:

```
[success] name = mister age = 30 [fail] name= null age = null
```

and my team manager want like this response:

```
[success] 200 success [fail] 400 error
```

Am I right or my boss right?
But when I think, if request doesn't carry the http status value,
how could I wrote like my team manager said? Or how can I write that side?

Answer (score 1):

Please read the comments below your last two questions a bit more carefully. ([I send some values to another url and about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43462707/i-send-some-valuse-to-another-url-and-about-that) and [how to get http status value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43464321/how-to-get-http-status-value))

As it states there your team manager is correct (no need for asking it a third time). I think you still confuse an HTTP request and response. The **request** is end by the *client* **requesting** a specific resource. The **server** then answers with a **result** *and* a status code depending on whether it was successful (`200 OK`) or not (`400 Bad Request`, `404 Not Found`, ...).

The status code is send by the server in an HTTP response. It is independent of the result that is included in the response, which would be your data values `name` and `age` for example.